# Sort view before print

Tags: views, entities

I have some node IDs I'm passing to a view; however the sort order is wrong.

Here's my pseudo code:

```
//query to grab the nids

if (!empty($nodeids)) {
  $view = 'taxo_listing';
  foreach ($nodeids as $nid) {
    print views_embed_view($view, block_1, $nid);
  }
}
```

What I need to do is pre-build the view then run implement `hook_views_query_alter` to sort the view before printing out the view.

Been looking at http://views.doc.logrus.com/ for a while now, but it's all a bit confusing, can anyone offer any clues as how to go about this? I know what I want to do but unsure how to go about it, sound familiar guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `$nodeids` comes from, but I expect it's an array of nids from a database query? If so, you're effectively running a view with a view and can probably get away without writing any code for hooks.

Therefore, you can either:

- Sort the `$nodeids` yourself with [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) which will mean probably returning more fields to sort with and maybe writing your own comparison function.
- Let Views handle all of this, thus gaining access to the UI and all it's powers.

The latter 'view within a view' approach is better for sustainability and sanity because it uses the Views UI and theme layers more consistently. A good approach that's worked for me is:

1. Make a view that can either:

   - return the properly sorted `$nodeids`, or;
   - get it to take an argument of a comma-separated list of nids you can pass `implode(',', $nodeids)` to.
2. use [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) to add a field that can contain your `views_embed_view($view, block_1, $nid)`, probably with `$nid` replaced by `$row->nid` but will depend on your setup.
3. Add any sorting or sorting code to the view you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, The view in question accepts NIDS as arguments, but ignores the sort I have on 'title' using the wonderful view UI. The query is run on a separate table ie not the one that I have in my view. I was hoping that there was a way to pre-build a view, sort it then print it. Plus I would really like to learn more about how views works under the hood.

Comment: if you could tell more about what taxo_listing is doing/what you want it to do, that might shed some more light on an answer as well, as, to be blunt, views does not "ignore" sorts on titles

Comment: If you can see sorting on Live Preview and views_embed_view is not respecting it, it clearly is a bug in Views. views_embed_view is supposed to respect all argument, sorts, filters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) as well

> This hook is called right before the render process. The query has
>   been executed, and the pre_render() phase has already happened for
>   handlers, so all data should be available.

Example

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  // Scramble the order of the rows shown on this result page.
  // Note that this could be done earlier, but not later in the view execution
  // process.
  shuffle($view->result);
}
```

Read [Views hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7)